# URL conversion to a string in PHP

Tags: php, html

I found it many times that a url or link to a page is replaced with another string name like

```
         url=http//:www.google.com
         and it is converted into something like user_1604
```

How is that conversion done? Give your answer with PHP code.

Comment: Give your question with PHP code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do some basic tutorials for html, in html there is the anchor witch has an href attribute for the url

```
<a href="http://google.com">user_1604</a>
```

You can echo this with php

```
echo '<a href="http://google.com">user_1604</a>';
```